# Show that an equivalence class is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ a subspace of $V$.

Define the equivalence class $[$**x**$]=\{ $**y** $\in V:$ **x**-**y** $\in W\}$

Show that the equivalence class is an affine subspace, which is defined as the subspace $W$ translated by the vector  **x**$ \in V$ denoted $U = $**x**$+W$

In essence, show that [**x**] = **x** +$W$

---

So the following is my own solution but I am not sure if it is correct:

Let **a** $\in$ [**x**]

Then we have: (from now on I will not use italics to portray vectors for convenience)

$ x-a \in W \Rightarrow a-x \in W \Rightarrow a-x = w $, for some $ w \in W$
$\Rightarrow a = x +w \Rightarrow a \in x+ W$

Thus [**x**] $\subset $ **x**+$W$

And similarly, show that   **x**+$W$ $\subset $ [**x**]

Comment: if $x\in V$, then $x+V=V$...

Comment: I am not sure what you imply by that. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y \in [x] &\iff y - x \in W \\
        & \iff \exists w \in W( w = y - x ) \\
        & \iff \exists w \in W ( y = x + w ) \\
        & \iff y \in x + W.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus, $[x] = x + W$.